# SwiperJS: Custom speed/delay for each slide?

Tags: swiper.js

- Swiper Version: 5.3.

I would like to know whether there is an option to set individual slide duration/delay in [Swiper JS](https://swiperjs.com/) out of the box. I searched in the docs, github issues but couldn't find anything related.

If not available out of the box, can anyone show how to achieve this by hacking the core or custom code.

thanks.

Answer (score 7):

### data-swiper-autoplay

`data-swiper-autoplay` attribute:

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-autoplay

> Delay between transitions (in ms). If this parameter is not specified,
> auto play will be disabled
>
> If you need to specify different delay for specific slides you can do
> it by using data-swiper-autoplay (in ms) attribute on slide:

```js
<!-- hold this slide for 2 seconds -->
<div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="2000">
```

Example:

```css
html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.0.1/swiper-bundle.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <h1>Swiper 7 data-swiper-autoplay</h1>
  <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="3000">3 seconds</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="4000">4 seconds</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="5000">5 seconds</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.0.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
      initialSlide: 1,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 2000,
      },
      centeredSlides: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: There is a  way for [autoplay duration per slide with swiperAngular version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390988/13030959) here

Comment: The `speed` it's transition time. The `delay` is the time that is stopped in `autoplay`.